# Can't access Raspbian via SSH(and other services) after some time

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have the Raspberry Pi with Raspbian installed.

I am connected to internet with 3G Dongle. My issue is that after 2 hours uptime, I can't ssh into my rpi. I don't get any error, it just keeps connecting and when typing ssh -v it says that connection was established. Also, I can't access my website, and node applications. However, I can still ping and telnet to the raspberry. Sometimes I can access ssh for almost half a second.

Do you have any ideas what might be the problem?

I noticed when I connected with ssh for one second that after executing route -n there was no default gateway that has always been there when it was working.

Comment: How are you accessing the device over ssh? With a hostname or with an IP address?

Comment: I had a similar situation with my Raspberry type B, the problem was the electric source ... not enougth power. Are you sure that you got something strong enougth ?

Comment: @datUser 
I am accessing the device using ip address. Like this pi@123.123.123.123

Comment: @Carpette 
I am certain that this is not related to electric source. It's stable and it is giving enough power.